# Why doesn't JavaScript onclick work when an eventlistener is used?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm learning JavaScript and I'm having difficulty with making a button access a function using a `document.addEventListener(`.

I've been able to get it to work when I place the function inside the `<script> </script>` tag within the html, but not successful when I use a different .js file.

Here is an example:

My `js.js` file:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  // Use buttons to toggle between views
  document.querySelector('#inbox').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('inbox'));
  document.querySelector('#sent').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('sent'));
  document.querySelector('#archived').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('archive'));
  document.querySelector('#compose').addEventListener('click',  compose_email);
  document.getElementById("emailSent").onclick = function() {wawa()};
});

function wawa() {
  var variable = document.getElementById('compose-form').value;
  console.log("WE HERE", variable)
  send(variable)
}
```

Then my html:

```
{% load static %}

{% block body %}

    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="inbox">Inbox</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="compose">Compose</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="sent">Sent</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="archived">Archived</button>
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a>
    <hr>

    <div id="emails-view">
    </div>

    <div id="compose-view">
        <h3>New Email</h3>
        <form id="compose-form">
            <div class="form-group">
                From: <input disabled class="form-control" value="{{ request.user.email }}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                To: <input id="compose-recipients" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="compose-subject" placeholder="Subject">
            </div>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="compose-body" placeholder="Body"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  id="emailSent" />
        </form>
    </div>


   New !!!!
      <div id="content">
        </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
    <script src="{% static 'mail/inbox.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

When I push the submit button using the inspect function of the web browser nothing happens, and the console.log does not show anything.

Answer (score 0):

Are you including your js file somewhere in your html? Generally this will need to be included before the function you are wanting to use is invoked. Usually in the head.